# Incrementing and decrementing a matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, vector, row

I'm stuck with a problem I want to solve but don't figure it out.

For your information. In my university we use a .h file which our professor has written by himself to make it easier for us to create matrices and vectors.

The matrix looks like this:

```
  |1|2|3|4|
1.|5|4|3|1|
2.|2|1|8|4|
3.|3|0|7|6|
```

What I want to do now is to start from *row1* *column1* and go to *row1* *column4*. From there on I don't want to do the row-major-order. Instead I want to go to *row2* *column4* and move backward until *row2 column1*.

My code looks like this:

```
int i,j;

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for (j = 4; j <= 1; --j)
   {
     printf("j: %d", j);
   }
}
```

But this gives me:

```
i = 1
j= 4,3,2,1
i = 2
j= 4,3,2,1
.....
```

But I want it to be like:

```
i = 1
j = 1,2,3,4
i = 2
j = 4,3,2,1
.....
```

How can I get this like I want it to be?

Cheers!

Comment: This loop `for (j = 4; j <= 1; --j)` will not be entered, because the stopping condition is satisfied before the loop begins.

Comment: @jxh why? j will start at 4 and decrement to 1. Or do I not understand your answer?

Comment: `4 <= 1` evaluates to false, so the loop stops.

Comment: @jxh But the loop works for me. j doesn't has to be 1 to start. I set j to 4 because I have 4 columns and --j decrements it to 1. And when it gets to 1, then the loop stops.

Comment: @Lionel Ronaldo And what about i equal to 3?

Comment: FYI, this is called a boustrophedonic traversal of the matrix.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for the information. Where can I find out more about this? I didn't find something on google.

Comment: https://tio.run/##HcxBCsIwFATQ/T/FUBES2giiK9N6F0ms/o8mpVY3JWePSVcD84Zx5uFc3nFwr6@/o/8snuPheSXisOB94wD1i@w11lwb7sQSjXGGYgw4WjD6AaeSbatpJQCbStGzhVQtK2NEV9sGwDSXs1E1csHeNx1E2wqJUk75Dw

Comment: @jxh I'm sorry if this sounded like this. That clearly was not my intention. All I wanted to say is that the way I had it in my code worked so I don't know. Maybe just my compiler is stupid :D But how would you write the for-loop to get it the I described it?

Comment: At the moment, your question does not provide a reproducible sample to work from. The output you show does not match the output that your sample tries to provide, and the sample does not read to perform the way you describe it should perform. From the surface, it appears you have not put forth sufficient effort to solve the problem yourself, and are asking people to do the work for you. I know this is probably not the case. But, I am asking you to put in the work to make your program in your question match the behavior you describe in your question. Thanks.

Comment: When I say "reproducible sample", I mean reproducing the errant behavior that you describe. The code you provide does not provide any output, because the inner loop is not entered at each iteration of the outer loop. When I say "make your program ... match the behavior you describe ...", I am asking you to provide a program that reproduces the errant behavior.

Comment: @jxh I was able to figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf(" %d",a[i][j]);
    else
        for(j=n-1; j>=0; j--)
            printf(" %d",a[i][j]);
}
```

m and n are dimensions of an mxn matrix. Basically, you have to check if the row is even or odd, and based on that you move either from the start or the end of that row.
**EDIT**: Just to clarify, `a` is a name of a matrix created before, with values entered by user. Here it is, if it helps you further understand.

```
int i, j, m, n, a[MAX][MAX];
printf(" m= ");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf(" n= ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf(" Matrix:\n");
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

`MAX` is defined outside of main function, before it, with

```
#define MAX 100
```

Comment: Where did you put the m dimension? I can not find it in the code

Comment: My bad, it's supposed to be in the first loop. I will edit it now.